# vb.net return actual chart x and y values on mousemove

Tags: vb.net, charts

In my simple vb.net chart that displays a particular series, I would like to obtain running values of the actual values in the chart.  I can already obtain the x-y coordinates, which is easy (e.x and e.y) - but wondering if there is a available method to convert the coordinates to the values related to the chart itself.

I need to use the mousemove event rather than mousedown.

I wish to transfer these actual values to a textbox on the form.

Thanks - burnt out trying to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy, unless the chart control doesn't give you some crucial information, in which case it's pretty hard :)

Your chart control probably shows several elements: the chart itself (bounded by the X and Y axes), the chart title, the axis titles, maybe a legend, etc. What you need to know is the .Left and .Width values of your X-axis. Assuming you can obtain those, the formula you want is

```
actualX = (mouseX - axis.Left) / axis.Width * (axis.Max - axis.Min) + axis.Min
```

Without knowing what chart control you're using on which platform, it's hard to tell you how to find all those pieces, but the formula is what you're looking for.